# Fresh download of wso2 G-Reg server throws NoClassDefFoundError exception on startup

Tags: java, middleware, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

During start-up the logs show a NoClassDefFoundError exception for class javax/servlet/ServletContextAttributeListener right after successfully loading StandardContext STRATOS_ROOT:

```
[2014-11-14 17:03:35,840] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext}
- Error configuring application listener of class 
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextAttributeListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Environment: Windows 7 x64, Oracle JDK 7 (build 1.7.0_71-b14)

Is anybody else experiencing this issue?
Any advice on how to get it working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your java version, use java 6(1.6). Then it will work!